# Is there a way to use the Minus Command to determine which fields are different?

Tags: sql, peoplesoft, peoplecode

I have 2 records that I want to run the MINUS command against.

The first record is a listing of "brand new" data.  The second record is a compilation of all the "brand new" data that has already been processed.

I know how to easily generate the data... IE....

```
Select A, B, C, D from X
Minus
Select A, B, C, D from Y
```

What I'm wondering, is there a way for the code to tell me that D or C were the fields that didn't match up?

My 2 records have 34 fields and, when I have to do an update, the coding is going to be long and a pain.

Any tips or tricks to shorten this process?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you have a key for these tables? Like anything you could join on to determine whether something is totally new instance or new version of an existing record with different values?

Comment: If just one column differs, you want that information. And if 2 differs, or 33?

Comment: Sadly, there is only 1 shared Key.  The would be Employee ID.

Comment: That is correct Jarlh!   I want to find out which fields are different and only use those for updating.  Thanks!

Comment: For the same Employee ID?

Comment: Yes.  So, if the first field is Employee ID(K) in both Record A & B, then, where there is a difference between fields in A & B, tell me which fields have the difference(s).